# Application Crashes On Clicking Facebook Native Ads requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Tags: android, facebook, networking, native-ads, audience

Application crashes when user click on facebook native ads

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:345)
    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3660)
    at com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
```

Facebook Android SDK version:
com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1